# How can split words with spaces with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a hangman game in JavaScript. React actually. I got it all working except I was to support multiple words. Meaning, the spaces must exist but not be considered in the logic to determine completion of the game.

The snippet below is how I am getting the `answer` which is a prop passed based on the keyboard hits and splitting it to get the characters. Then, I map the letters and inside the map function I make a ternary evaluation against a `correctedLetters` prop value which contains the real word they're guessing.

```
{answer.split('').map((letter, index) => {
    const l = letter.toUpperCase();
    return (
      <Text key={index} style={[{color: activeColors.textcolor}, styles.text]}>
        {correctLetters.includes(l) ? l : '-'}
      </Text>
    )
  })}
```

What I would like to do is show two or more sets of dashes depending on whether the answer is one word or two. See the image to see what I mean. That dash in the middle is just a space. Technically, I should've won here

Kind of like a Wheel of Fortune actually.

[image]

Comment: Have a statement that chacks if what you have typed is equal to the first word part then if it is add a dash and move on to the second part of the word or phrase. - Is that kinda what you want/need?

Comment: No, I don't think that's right. I dont add the dashes as the user writes. The dashes are preplaced showing how many characters are in the word. In case of a phrase, then there would multiple sets of dashes. I do susbtitute the dashes for the correct pressed letters. That part is already done. The screenshot shows the finished state of the game for that word (Kumi Kata). But it's not finishing because there is a dash that is not a letter. It's just a space. I need to be able to find the spaces and render my dashes in that way. For example, for this word in the screenshot, it should be ---- ----

Comment: So the dash should be a space? Correct.

Comment: you can use answer.split(' ') with a space in it, split the wrods first then split the letters fore each word might be the way to go?

Comment: This question is somewhat hard to understand Im pretty knowledge of React but right now cant understand if the dash is supposed to be a space or another letter.

Comment: Here is a wrap-up: after splitting the answer to letters, he will compare the letters with a correct letters that he already has. the problem occurs when the answer contains a space, then because of `correctLetters.includes(l) ? l : '-'` any space will be converted to a dash which will affect the final result checking and will make it as a wrong answer.

Comment: it took me around 15 mins to understand the question, you have to edit it to be understandable. and I think providing the code that checks winning/losing would make it clear to get the right support.

Comment: `'Kumi Kata'.replace(/\S/g, '-')` gives `---- ----`.

Comment: Sorry guys. I tried my best to explained it but I complicated it instead. It's a regular game of hangman. The dashes are the letters that you need to guess. The spaces would not be dashes. They would be spaces. So, Stack Overflow would ----- -------

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of this code `correctLetters.includes(l) ? l : '-'`, any space will be converted to a dash, thus, if the answer contains two words the user will never win because I think you are checking for the dashes to decide if a user won or lost.

You have to check first if `letter` is a real letter or it's just a whitespace, hence, if it's `" "` you'll add a space else add a letter/dash.

```
{answer.split('').map((letter, index) => {
    if (letter === " ") return <Text>{" "}</Text>

    const l = letter.toUpperCase();
    return (
      <Text key={index} style={[{color: activeColors.textcolor}, styles.text]}>
        {correctLetters.includes(l) ? l : '-'}
      </Text>
    )
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [MHD Alaa Alhaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7918037/mhd-alaa-alhaj)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78104320/10415695), you need to determine if the current character in your loop is a space, however, if you don't plan on using the result of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can forgo it and use a traditional for loop and a simple ternary operator.

```js
{
  const characters = answer.split("");
  for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    const character = characters[i];
    const uppercase = character.toUpperCase();
    return (
      character === " "
    ) ? (
      <Text key={index}>{" "}</Text>
    ) : (
      <Text key={index} style={[{color: activeColors.textcolor}, styles.text]}>
        {correctLetters.includes(uppercase) ? uppercase : "-"}
      </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

You can also use the ternary operator inside the second `<Text />` element (in the `OR` part of the ternary operator) to maintain the same style for each character including spaces. Please note that in this version, the key (index) is preserved for all characters including spaces.

Good luck.

Comment: This one I couldn't figure out within the code. It can't go in JSX and some is JSX. But I got the one above to work. Thank you tho. Plus 1 anyway

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working my friend, best of luck with your project!